# Intel Pro 1000 Adapters iSCSI, boot device and LACP

Tags: iscsi

I'm currently testing iSCSI with Intel Pro 1000 PT DualPort adapter. The performance is pretty well but is it possible to combine both ethernet ports to have a true 2Gbit link for the boot device? Intel documentation doesn't explain this.

Comment: How about some detail, such as what OS you're talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is multipath i/o (MPIO). There are different ways to configure this based on OS and san type and You're not giving us a lot of info to work on. Here's an article about iscsi mpio using microsoft's iscsi initiator and a Dell san. It should at least get you started.

http://www.delltechcenter.com/page/MPIO+to+PowerVault+MD3000i+with+Microsoft+iSCSI+Initiator

This is also good reading on why you shouldn't use link aggregation with iscsi:

http://virtualgeek.typepad.com/virtual_geek/2009/01/a-multivendor-post-to-help-our-mutual-iscsi-customers-using-vmware.html

Comment: +1, If the NIC supports iSOE it might have built in MPIO, I know Broadcom NICs do (haven't used Intel, but expect they do). If there isn't iSOE then it's an OS function and Windows definitely support MPIO once enabled; most *nix OSes do as well.

Answer (score -2):

That's typically through a combination of OS software and networking equipment to accomplish that - a.k.a. channel bonding, ether channeling, trunking, etc.

Comment: -1 sorry but iscsi shouldn't use trunking.

Comment: I guess you missed the "etc..."

Comment: All the terms you listed are synonyms for link aggregation, which should not be used with iscsi. What did you mean to indicate by saying "etc"?

Comment: "a combination of OS software and networking equipment" Are you saying/stating MPIO is anything different?